# Integral of $ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 8x + 5}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve:

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 8x + 5}} dx$$

This question is from a list and it's in the category of problems that involving $\sqrt{x^2\pm a^2}$ and $\sqrt{a^2\pm x^2}$ (triangle rules).
I tried some methods, but I didn't get anywhere. Where this type of problem fits?

Comment: Where it fits: The thing inside the square root is $(2x+2)^2+1$.  Let $u=2x+2$. Then $dt=\frac{du}{2}$ and $x=\frac{u-2}{2}$. So we are integrating $\frac{1}{4}\frac{u-2}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$.  Completing the square is a useful tool.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Now I can see.. I was look for something like $\sqrt{u^2\pm a^2}$ as you found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (4x^2+8x+5) = 8(x+1), $$
so add and subtract $1$ in the numerator:
$$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 8x + 5}} \, dx = \int \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 8x + 5}} \, dx - \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 8x + 5}} \, dx $$

The first integral is then in the form $(f)^{-1/2}f'$, which is easy to integrate.

For the other, complete the square on the denominator:
$$ 4x^2+8x+5 = 4(x+1)^2 + 1 $$
This transforms the integral into one of the form
$$ \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{a^2y^2+1}}, $$
(with here $y=x+1$, $a=2$) which you can then turn into one of the forms you know how to do.